# Buildfarms : Options

Tags: language-agnostic, distributed, compiler-construction, buildfarm

We use Incredibuild here to compile our code in a distributed fashion. I was wondering if there are any open source (or free) alternatives to use on a home network?

Failing that, are there any other simple solutions with good integration with Visual Studio out there?

EDIT: I should say that I am quite happy to get my hands dirty and manually configure everything on each machine should that be required.

Comment: You're only interested in MSVC++ as the compiler?

Comment: Ideally yes but interested in other options as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't look past [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as a CI environment - among other features it allows multiple build agents to be linked together in one build grid.

Oh and it also has excellent integration with VS and SubVersion.  And it's free to use, up to a maximum of 20 build configurations and 2 build agents.